# How to call each item of a collection

Tags: vba, excel, collections

I managed to store a range of cells to a collection.

I am trying to use each item of the collection.

I failed to call it by using `Collection.Item` and `debug.Print` to show it in the Immediate window.

This works if I store only one cell into the collection.

```
lastRowIndex = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set PGname = New Collection
Set HScode = New Collection
For i = 1 To lastRowIndex
    PGname.Add Range((Cells(i, 1)), (Cells(i, 2)))
    HScode.Add (Cells(i, 2))
Next i
Debug.Print PGname.Item(1)  'this does not work
Debug.Print HScode.Item(1)  'this works
```

Comment: What usually happens why you try to `debug.print` a range object?

Comment: @CallumDA33 It is Run-time error '13': Type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
    Dim i                   As Long
    Dim lastRowIndex        As Long
    Dim PGname              As Object
    Dim HScode              As Object

    lastRowIndex = 10

    Set PGname = New Collection
    Set HScode = New Collection
    For i = 1 To lastRowIndex
        PGname.Add Range((Cells(i, 1)), (Cells(i, 2)))
        HScode.Add (Cells(i, 2))
    Next i
    Debug.Print PGname.Item(1).Address
    Debug.Print PGname.Item(1)(1)(1) 'this would print you cell A1

End Sub
```

You get an error, because you were trying to print a range of more than once cell. 
Take a look at the two debug.prints. Put some value in A1 to make sure what it prints.

Comment: Yes, What I am trying to do is print a range of at least 2 cells into another cell after store it by a collection. Because I want to do something with the data in the collection. Your code just print the cell A1 so It is not what I need. Do you have any other idea? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you give screenshot with an example. With some expectred input and output?